# Make Hudson check for new Release directory in the tag directory of the SVN and build the new release

Tags: hudson

### Question

Is there a ways to make Hudson check for new Release directory in the tag directory of the SVN repository and build only the new release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to create an SVN tag and then have Hudson build off that tag.  You can't do that with the standard Hudson as the SVN URL will change each time you create a new tag.

How about switching things around so that your developers check into a fixed SVN branch, then you have Hudson create a tag for each successful build ?  That's easy enough to do by adding an "execute shell" build step to create the SVN tag after the main build steps.

Comment: When we perform a release, in the repository in the tags directory a new folder gets created labeled with the project name and the version number.  What we want to do is to have hudson automatically check the tags directory in the repository to see if a new release folder was added to the directory.  If it has, we want hudson to build using the project .sln file that is in that new folder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have set it up the other way around. You need to set up a post commit trigger in SVN. So SVN tells Hudson when to build and what the tag is that needs to be build.